# How do I get lua to run on a mac OS X 10.11.6

Tags: lua

I downloaded the lua files and "installed" them using the 'make' command.
However, evidently, one just does not type the command lua in the terminal (unlike say python) to get lua to run.

If, in terminal, I go to the lua src directory, and enter ./lua, it will come up.

I.e. Lua 5.3.3  Copyright (C) 1994-2016 Lua.org, PUC-Rio

> 

I also made an alias 
lua="home directory path /lua-5.3.3/src/lua" it will come up; and if I enter say 
lua hello.lua; the lua hello text file will run as expected.

This sure seems to be a somewhat convoluted way to call lua up. 
Am I doing this correctly, or did I miss something?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to run `make install` or `sudo make install` in the lua directory

Comment: Thank you, that was it exactly.  I believe that the last time that I used the make process was on my old G5 and early version of Gimp, so I had forgotten the two (build, install) process.